# Using multiple Templates per section

Tags: templating, entries

I'm using this [support article](https://craftcms.com/support/entry-type-templates) as a guide and I'm stuck on what I'm doing wrong.

I have an "events" section, and I would like to use a different template for one the entries.  I've created a new entry type in the "events" section and gave it the handle "summerpreview."  I created a template in the "events" subfolder: "_types" entitled: "summerpreview.html."  That template uses the include tag:

```
{% include "events/_types/" ~ summerpreview.html %}
```

I've created an entry inside the "events" section using the "summer preview" entry type and gave it the slug of "summerpreview."

What am I missing here?  The entry pulls using the default "events" template and not the "summerpreview."  What do I need to do for this event to use "summerpreview" template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow the `entry.type` value to be part of the `include` path...

```
{% include "events/_types/" ~ entry.type %}
```

Since your `entry.type` is "summerpreview", that will be parsed out like this...

```
{% include "events/_types/summerpreview" %}
```

With Craft, you don't need to specify the `.html` extension, so this include should work perfectly.

---

As a side note... I'd recommend turning on `devMode` locally. It would have thrown an error, telling you that `summerpreview` is not a legitimate variable.

> [What Dev Mode Does](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode)